# Find the CDF of $\min(1,X)$

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be a uniform on $[0,2]$, find the cumulative distribution function of $Y=\min(1,X)$.

So here I what I did:

$F_Y(y)=0$ if $y<0$. If $0 \leq y < 1$, then $F_Y(y)=P(\min(1,X) \leq y)=P(X \leq y)=y/2$. If $y \geq 1$ then $F_Y(y)=P(\min(1,X) \leq y)=1 $.

Is this correct? (I am unsure because the CDF is apparently not continuous.)

Comment: But $F_Y(1)=1$.

Comment: Deal with $y\lt 0$, easy, Then deal with $0\le y\lt 1$. Note the change, very important.  Then deal with $y\ge 1$.

Comment: @nicolas: I just changed my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $F_Y(y)=0$ if $y<0$. If $0 \leq y < 1$, then $F_Y(y)=P(\min(1,X) \leq y)=P(X \leq y)=y/2$. If $y \geq 1$ then $F_Y(y)=P(\min(1,X) \leq y)=1 $.
>
> Is this correct? (I am unsure because the CDF is apparently not continuous.)

In summary:

$$F_Y(y)  = \begin{cases}0 & : y< 0 \\ y/2 & : 0\leq y < 1 \\ 1 & : 1\leq y \end{cases}$$

This is correct.   The CDF of Y, as you noticed, is not continuous.   There is a step-discontinuity at $Y=1$, which should be expected due to the fact that $Y=\min(1, X)$.   $Y$ has a mixed probability distribution.   $Y$ behaves as a continuous random variable over the interval $(0;1)$ but it behaves as a discrete random variable at the point $Y=1$; having a probability mass there: $\mathsf P(Y=1)=\tfrac 1 2$.